# Can you save an array of ViewControllers locally (NSKeyedArchiver) in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiviewcontroller, nskeyedarchiver

I'm currently hired to create the data handling part of a local document iOS application. I wasn't involved in creating the UserInterface and so I'm in need of help.

**The problem:**
The person(s) that created the user interface implemented all the data needed to be saved only in the view controller, and they use the model to save an array of view controllers.

I have tried saving this array locally onto the disc using FileManager and NSKeyedArchiver. I have also tried using NSUserDefaults. They didn't enable core data in the initial application either and the package is a little messy which doesn't help.

Below is the code I wrote in the DocumentPageModel.swift file which tries to save an array of ViewControllers...

```
static let DocumentsDirectory =  try! FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)


//static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("meals")

// Save the data onto drive (Called when the 'save' button is pressed on a create new case page
public func saveData() {
    NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(CasePageModel.cases, toFile: CasePageModel.ArchiveURL.path)
    //listOfTasks = CasePageModel.cases
    print("Successfully saved")
}


private var listOfTasks: [CaseViewController] {
    get {
        return (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: CasePageModel.ArchiveURL.path) as? [CaseViewController])! // ??[]
    }
    set {
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(CasePageModel.cases, toFile: CasePageModel.ArchiveURL.path)
    }
}

// Retrieves data saved and makes it: var cases
// Called when view is loaded.
public func retrieveData() {
    CasePageModel.cases = listOfTasks
    print("Successfully loaded")
    print("\(CasePageModel.cases.count)")

    /*
     if let arrayOfCases: NSArray = UserDefaults.object.(forKey: "cases") as! NSArray {
     CasePageModel.cases = arrayOfCases
     }
     */
}
```

This saves the array fine, But when calling the retrieveData, the variables/data supposedly saved in a ViewController is 'nil' throwing an uncaught exception.

**Question:**
Is there actually any way to save the viewController **and** it's state within an array and save **that** array locally? 
I could possibly implement a correct version of the 'model' but because the previous developers developed 10+ view controllers and one model, I believe it will be hard to create seperate models for all of them, seeing as though Images, Voice Recordings and external notes are inputted... So if anyone knows any way to possible save the ViewController with it's variables locally, Please help me!!

Thanks in advance, I've been working on trying to save this for hours..

Comment: Dont think trying to save whole viewController in disk is a good idea, rather just save its data in disk and restore later, or use [preserving viewcontroller](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html) if you want to quit and resume at launch

Comment: @Tj3n I understand that saving a whole viewController isn't the best idea. But since the previous developer didn't create multiple models to keep track and keep hold of the input information of the app (Names, Dates, images, external notes).. And furthermore, The only model file they created was a file which held all of the viewcontrollers (and their variables) in an array. So I don't want to meddle with any of the functionality they've created as I cannot understand their code.

Comment: well that's seriously code smell, I think your saving doesn't work, since view controller doesn't confront to `NSCoding`, if you implement this, you will be able to save it in `NSUserDefault` or as files

Answer (score 0):

You can store any model class object in NSUserDefaults using NSCoding.

Example:

```
import UIKit
```

class ClassName: NSObject {

```
var  customerID:Int!

override init() {}


required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    if let customerID = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("customerID") as? Int {
        self.customerID = totalHoldingCost
    }


}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {

    aCoder.encodeObject(customerID, forKey: "customerID")
}
```

}

Comment: This makes sense! This is how i'm trying to go about it.. However, seeing as though I cannot communicate the previous developer, and the code is so messy, It's not possible for me to do this efficiently without basically starting the whole project again from scratch which won't be posisble in my timespan. If you know any way of saving a view controller and it's variables(Text fields, etc) Then please let me know! :)

Otherwise, I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use App State Restoration to store the complete state of your controllers with all of its objects.. Try these tutorials --

> https://www.raywenderlich.com/117471/state-restoration-tutorial
>
> http://useyourloaf.com/blog/state-preservation-and-restoration/